# Do all HVAC units have a drain line?

Tags: hvac

I have a rental unit and I can not find a condensation drain line on the home heating unit. The unit is old and my question is do all heating units have a condensation drain?
Thank you

Comment: Is it heat only? If so then I don't see the need for a condensation drain, as little or no condensing will take place.

Answer (score 4):

A furnace only has a drain if it's a high efficiency condensing unit, or it contains an A/C evaporator coil.

If it's an older non-high efficiency unit, and there's no integrated air conditioning. Then it probably won't have any type of drain.